# Existence of matrices with some invertibility properties

Tags: matrices, determinants, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

Prove that there exists five  matrices $B_i \in \mathbb{F}_2^{5\times 10}$, $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, such that any two $B_i$'s form an invertible matrix in $\mathbb{F}_2^{10\times 10}$.

I am interested in a proof of existence that could be generalized to matrices with other dimensions.

Follow-up question when there are constraints on the $B_i$'s:  [Existence of matrices in $\mathbb{F}_2$ with some invertibility properties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405296/existence-of-matrices-in-mathbbf-2-with-some-invertibility-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$, $B'$ are $5\times 10$ matrices of rank $5$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, the condition that the matrix formed by stacking $B$ on top of $B'$ is invertible is equivalent to the condition that the row span of $B$ and the row span of $B'$ have trivial intersection. The row spans are $5$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^{10}$, so given five $5$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^{10}$ with pairwise trivial intersection, we can choose bases for them to construct matrices $B_1,\ldots,B_5$.

Note that $\mathbb{F}_2^{10}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}^2$ as an $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector space. A $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$-subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}^2$ can be identified with a $5$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$ subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^{10}$, and every pair of $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$-subpsaces of $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}^2$ have trivial intersection. There are 33 such subspaces, so we can find even find $B_1,\ldots,B_{33}\in\mathbb{F}_2^{5\times 10}$ with the desired property.

Comment: (1) One can make this even more explicit by choosing a basis for $\mathbb F_{2^5}$, letting us write each entry as a $5 \times 5$ matrix, and forming the $5 \times 10$ matrices by stacking two of them on top of each other. (2) One can check that 33 is the optimal number, since $\mathbb F_{2^10}$ contains $2^{10}-1$ nonzero vectors, with $2^5 -1$ in each subspace, so the maximum number of nonintersecting subspaces is at most $2^{10}-1/ (2^5-1)= 2^5+1 =33$.

Comment: @Julian Rosen Can this solution be adapted to this case https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405296/existence-of-matrices-in-mathbbf-2-with-some-invertibility-properties where there are some constraints on the structure of the Bi's?